# With Next 13, how do you display images in a grid with the same width and height despite having various dimensions?

Tags: javascript, image, next.js, frontend, grid

In Next 12, my blog has a component that fits images to have the same dimensions

```html
    <div
      key={title}
      className="flex flex-col rounded-lg shadow-lg overflow-hidden"
    >
      <div className="flex-shrink-0">
        <Image
          className="w-full object-cover"
          height={300}
          width={600}
          src={cover_image}
          alt={title}
        />
    </div>
```

the website looks as following [image]

However, on new update the image are all over the place
[image]

From further inspection it seems to be related directly to original image dimensions. However, the image dimensions on next/image height and width do not seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried setting `aspect-[2/1]` on the `Image`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Image from "next/legacy/image";
```

solves the issue temporarily