# How does the Image component in NextJs 13 works?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, nextjs-image, next.js13

I have implemented the custom loader as per docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

```js
import Image from 'next/image'

const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
  return `https://example.com/${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`
}

const MyImage = (props) => {
  return (
    <Image
      loader={myLoader}
      src="me.png"
      alt="Picture of the author"
      width={500}
      height={500}
    />
  )
}
```

The quality does not change either its 10 or 100. The width and height react similarly.
Additionally, here is a post on fixing Image component in a project: [With Next 13, how do you display images in a grid with the same width and height despite having various dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74391088/with-next-13-how-do-you-display-images-in-a-grid-with-the-same-width-and-height)
The issue was solved by moving to `legacy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks odd, It could be a cache problem in the application or cache in the browser. It is also possible that the parameters in the loader are not working properly. If the quality parameter doesn't work, Next js will assume its quality to be 75.

You can try by adding priority to image

```
<Image
  loader={myLoader}
  src="me.png"
  alt="Picture of the author"
  width={500}
  height={500}
  priority
/>
```

Or add unoptimized config by updating `next.config.js` with the following configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
}
```

Comment: congrats on the bounty, i have tried the solution, still the same quality unoptimized image, returned back to legacy import

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm glad your problem has been solved. Yes, since Next.js 13, The next/image component was rewritten to improve performance and developer experience. But still compatible with old next/image by using `next/legacy/image`